# org.springframework.cloud VS io.awspring.cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

what is the difference between these maven group ids. I see few examples on internet using org.springframework.cloud and other using io.awspring.cloud
Is one preferred over other ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an [April 17, 2020 announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/17/spring-cloud-aws-2-3-is-now-available#why-has-the-package-name-changed), Spring Cloud AWS is no longer part of the Spring Cloud release train. Not being part of the release train means moving out of the Spring Cloud organization on GitHub and having new Maven coordinates and package names.

If you want the newest Spring Cloud AWS code, use group ID io.awspring.cloud.

Comment: so io.awspring.cloud to be used?

Comment: Yes. I edited the answer to make that explicit.